# How can I find the final URL after all redirections in Perl?

Tags: perl, url, redirect

Lets say I have "http://www.ritzcarlton.com" and that redirects me to "http://www.ritzcarlton.com/en/Default.htm". Is there a way in Perl to find the end url after all the redirects?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using LWP will follow the redirections for you. You can then interrogate the `HTTP::Request` object to find out the URI it requested.

```
use LWP::UserAgent qw();

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $response = $ua->get('http://www.ritzcarlton.com');

print $response->request->uri . "\n";
```

Output is:

> http://www.ritzcarlton.com/en/Default.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you're issuing HTTP requests yourself, then the redirect URL will be in the returned `Location:` header. If you're using a proper HTTP client like [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm) or [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm), which is what you should be doing, redirection is handled automatically.